# I can't configure OpenID for Login at Facebook

Tags: gmail, facebook, openid, login

I want to use my Google Account as OpenID login at Facebook.

So after some Googling I found [this Facebook help page](https://www.facebook.com/help/155414354524884/), but at the Settings page there is no section "Linked Accounts", it looks like this:

[image]

Is this feature disabled by Facebook?